# Algunos nuevos colores en los estilos del sitio son disruptivos

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Hola chicos estoy notando la entrada del cambio de colores en el esquema del tema del sitio.

Y hasta ahora me entero de que hay ciertos elementos que han quedado como disruptivos por ejemplo la ayuda de los comentarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gusta la iniciativa y el cambio de color pero por lo menos en este caso agradecería que las letras hubiesen quedado en color blanco.

Agradezco su apoyo en la petición y que también agreguen aquí todo aquello que les parece que no es legible o irrumpe en la utilidad que debe mantener el sitio.

Comment: hay una publicacion en meta.. los bugs alla!!! no importa donde los ven o no... https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394232/141717

Answer (score 1):

Entendiendo que esta publicación no la leerá nadie con el poder de corregir algo, pero por dar algo de vida a este foro, adjunto los problemas que veo

#### 1.- El scroll muestra figuras extrañas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 2.- Poca diferencia entre el contraste de las publicaciones visitadas vs las no visitadas

Antes con los colores "más fueres" era notorio a simple vista, ahora me cuesta procesar si he visitado o no esa publicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los bugs, a meta... a la publicacion original.. aca nadie puede hacer nada...

Comment: y ponganlos que los estan revisando y corrigiendo!!

Comment: No veo lo del scroll por ningun lado.. lo otro si.. sera algo de tu navegador?

Comment: juega con el zoom a ver si se corrige?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Nop, no lo corrige  :(